# Estoy realizando una aplicación en Android Studio, y al compilar la aplicación para ver su simulación, me ha aparecido el siguiente mensaje en rojo

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el error que aparece. No sé a qué se debe y no me gustaría empezar el proyecto desde cero.

Comment: Hola Sheyla, tanto el código como los mensajes de error, deben estar en formato texto, no en imágenes, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, de esa forma lograrás que sea mejor recibida y evitarás recibir votos negativos. Saludos.

Comment: Tal vez el problema es tu Android Manifest.xml, te sugiero agregarlo a tu pregunta, agrega mas información, revisar [ask]